# Windows Live Writer plugin with .NET 4

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, side-by-side, windows-live-writer

Has anyone written a plugin for Windows Live Writer that runs against .NET 4?  I've read the .NET 4 introduces side-by-side running, so one part of the app can target .NET x and another part can target .NET 4.

I thought WLW would be a good starting point to try this as previously it only supported plugins up to .NET 2.  But my .NET 4 plugin never shows.

Maybe they test dependencies before loading the plugins?

Anyone else got this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  It can only run with the version of .NET Framework that was loaded by the application.

Answer (score 1):

You can load both .NET 2 and .NET 4 into the same process if your are using COM in between.

See [How To Use a .NET 4 Based DLL From .NET 2 Based Application?](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2011/05/30/how-to-use-a-net-4-based-dll-from-net-2-based-application.aspx) for more details